# Google App Engine: efficient large deletes (about 90000/day)

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have an application that has only one Model with two StringProperties.

The initial number of entities is around 100 million (I will upload those with the bulk loader).

Every 24 hours I must remove about 70000 entities and add 100000 entities. My question is now: what is the best way of deleting those entities?

Is there anyway to avoid fetching the entity before deleting it? I was unable to find a way of doing something like:

```
DELETE from xxx WHERE foo1 IN ('bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3', ...)
```

I realize that app engine offers an IN clause (albeit with a maximum length of 30 (because of the maximum number of individual requests per GQL query [1](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html))), but to me that still seems strange because I will have to get the x entities and then delete them again (making two RPC calls per entity).

Note: the entity should be ignored if not found.

**EDIT: Added info about problem**

These entities are simply domains. The first string being the SLD and the second the TLD (no subdomains). The application can be used to preform a request like this http://[...]/available/stackoverflow.com . The application will return a True/False json object.

Why do I have so many entities? Because the datastore contains all registered domains (.com for now). I cannot perform a whois request in every case because of TOSs and latency. So I initially populate the datastore with an entire zone file and then daily add/remove the domains that have been registered/dropped... The problem is, that these are pretty big quantities and I have to figure out a way to keep costs down and add/remove 2*~100000 domains per day.

Note: there is hardly any computation going on as an availability request simply checks whether the domain exists in the datastore!

[1](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html): ' A maximum of 30 datastore queries are allowed for any single GQL query.' (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If are not doing so already you should be using `key_names` for this.

You'll want a model something like:

```
class UnavailableDomain(db.Model):
    pass
```

Then you will populate your datastore like:

```
UnavailableDomain.get_or_insert(key_name='stackoverflow.com')
UnavailableDomain.get_or_insert(key_name='google.com')
```

Then you will query for available domains with something like:

```
is_available = UnavailableDomain.get_by_key_name('stackoverflow.com') is None
```

Then when you need to remove a bunch of domains because they have become available, you can build a big list of keys without having to query the database first like:

```
free_domains = ['stackoverflow.com', 'monkey.com']
db.delete(db.Key.from_path('UnavailableDomain', name) for name in free_domains)
```

I would still recommend batching up the deletes into something like 200 per RPC, if your free_domains list is *really* big

Comment: And this should have the best performance/least costs for this case?

Comment: Doing datastore operations directly with Keys is as cheap as you can get, and batching together operations is the best way to reduce CPU load for multiple actions. You'll want to play with the size of the batches to delete at a time to get as many keys deleted without going over the 1MB per RPC limit or hitting any timeouts. Also worth noting that pricing will not be CPU based in the near future.

Comment: Ah. Thats good news with the new pricing. And yeah I will play with the size, although apart for the initial list this is not too big (about 1MB per 50000 domains). Thanks!

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work yet. I am getting a 'Cannot operate on different entity groups in a transaction' error. I guess this has to do with the fact that these entities are all root entities and thus not part of the same group. Does that mean that I cannot use keys like this in a batched way (without giving them all a parent)?

Comment: are you running them in a transaction? If so ... don't :)

Comment: I think get_or_insert() (from your example, I didn't use that before) is by default a transactional operation... So I guess the question is, can I still do it using keys? It would seem that if I wanted to use keys I would have to loop through the transactions OR create a common parent (probably not a good idea). What do you think?

Comment: The 1MB API limit is no longer an issue for this - the SDK will automatically break up large batches into smaller ones to avoid too-large RPCs for you.

Comment: @o1iver `get_or_insert` is indeed a transactional function. Since you don't have any per-entity data, though, you don't need it - you can just overwrite an existing entity if it exists. Drop `get_or_insert` and just create the entity with `UnavailableDomain(key_name='stackoverflow.com')`. It's surprising you're getting that error, though - are you trying to use `get_or_insert` from within another transaction?

Comment: @nick: Thanks for the two points (and great blog by the way :-)). I am not using get_or_insert 'within another transaction', but from what I could see from `google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py` `get_or_insert` calls `run_in_transaction(txn)` itself. But I will avoid using get_or_insert and just pass the object directly to `db.put()`.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered the [appengine-mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) library. It comes with the pipeline library and you could utilise both to:

- Create a pipeline for the overall task that you will run via cron every 24hrs
- The 'overall' pipeline would start a mapper that filters your entities and yields the delete operations
- after the delete mapper completes, the 'overall' pipeline could call an 'import' pipeline to start running your entity creation part.
- pipeline api can then send you an email to report on it's status

Comment: I just had a quick look at the pipeline library (didn't know it exists so thanks), the thing is, that I think it is a bit over the top. I never do any computations with those entities (they are only required there so that I can check whether or not it exists).

Without having looked at the lib in detail: wouldn't I still have to make the datastore RPC when filtering?

I just want to minimize CPU time...

Comment: Maybe you need to explain a bit more about your process then, as it sounds like you should be doing something with keys/key_names.

Comment: I have added some more information about my current use-case above! Thanks for the help!